# Openpyxl 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to run a simple piece of code (Python 3.6) to convert a range of cells in excel worksheet into a list. Here is the code:

```
import openpyxl

wb_d = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
ws = wb_d.active
# iterate through all rows in specific column openpyxl
mylist = []
for row in ws.iter_rows('A{}:A{}'.format(ws.min_row,ws.max_row)):
    for cell in row:
        mylist.append(cell.value)
print(mylist)
```

I am receiving an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PycharmProjects/Excel/list_generator.py", line 7, in <module>
    for row in ws.iter_rows('A{}:A{}'.format(ws.min_row,ws.max_row)):
  File "venv\Excel\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 438, in _cells_by_row
    for row in range(min_row, max_row + 1):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I tried also to define the range of cell as 'A1:A10' and also received an error. Could anyone please advice what is the problem with the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The input parameters for [`iter_rows()`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_rows) must be integers. So replace

```
for row in ws.iter_rows('A{}:A{}'.format(ws.min_row,ws.max_row))
```

with

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(ws.min_row,ws.max_row)
```

Comment: Or simply: `for row in ws`