# How do I print string values from excel column in python?

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to get the cell values (ticker symbols) from an Excel sheet, but cannot figure out how to specify the rows/columns to use. The ws.iter_rows() method is not accepting a string. Here is what I am using:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Users/SPAC_price_data.xlsx')
ws = wb['Common share price history']
for row in ws.iter_rows('A1:A36'):
    for cell in row:
            print(str(cell.value))
```

The error is:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-7fdf6dd1581e> in <module>
      1 if __name__ == "__main__":
----> 2      main()

<ipython-input-3-d2cdb2b8ed38> in main()
     16     wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Users/SPAC_price_data.xlsx')
     17     ws = wb['Common share price history']
---> 18     for row in ws.iter_rows('A1:A36'):
     19         for cell in row:
     20                 print(cell.value)

/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py in _cells_by_row(self, min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row, values_only)
    442 
    443     def _cells_by_row(self, min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row, values_only=False):
--> 444         for row in range(min_row, max_row + 1):
    445             cells = (self.cell(row=row, column=column) for column in range(min_col, max_col + 1))
    446             if values_only:

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Give us the whole error stack, here we can't know where the error comes from, not even the line that triggers it.

Comment: Just added, sorry

Comment: Can you share XLSX file?

Comment: I am just trying to get the values from the first column, which is a list of ticker symbols, e.g. A1: "ARYB", A2: "BMRG", etc.

Comment: The problem is that the method ws.iter_rows() is not accepting the cell numbers as an input, because it's a string (e.g. 'A1:A36')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input parameters for iter_rows() must be integers. So replace

```
for row in ws.iter_rows('C{}:C{}'.format(ws.min_row,ws.max_row)):
```

with

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(ws.min_row,ws.max_row):
```

As I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58245369/openpyxl-str-object-cannot-be-interpreted-as-an-integer)